# text doesn't show in mobile

Tags: html, css

Working on my test site - http://dev.nerdysyntax.com - and noticed on my Android certain text disappears. If you look at the "featured" section on an Android or maybe another mobile device, it's not there and on some of my other pages as well.

Is it font sizing? Can't seem to find out why the text disappears.

Comment: Tested on HTC Desire. Text looks fine to me.

Comment: Ok thanks maybe it is just on my Droid. Weird issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi...I checked on a Blackberry Curve and it shows.

My guess is that the Featured Work section appears in a `div` which is floated to the right and this is causing the problem.

Some mobile browsers handle `floats` in a weird way.  Check that it is not just dropped down below the main content.

I would suggest you style your mobile content without `floats` and serve it via a special mobile stylesheet.

Comment: Please explain more what you mean by styling it without floats. That content is associated with the sidebar of that section that is floated right so I'm not sure how I would leave just that content out of the float and still position it under the image.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible solutions for you:

1. Set a fallback font:

   ```
   #sidebar p {
       font-family: 'PTSansCaptionRegular', sans-serif;
   }
   ```
2. Try removing `float:right` from `#sidebar` and add `position:absolute` and `right:0`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Tried the font fallback before and that didn't work. As for removing the float, thanks for the alternative but on my Android it still doesn't show. Since both of you guys say you see it on your devices, I'm thinking maybe its an Droid issue.